Is there a difference between a w stat and z stat in a Mann Whitney test?
I have run a Mann Whitney test in R. The output is....
W = 108, p-value = 0.8789

I've been told to include the z statistic and p value.
How do I calculate the z statistic or is it the same as the W value?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330129/how-to-get-the-z-score-in-wilcox-test-in-r
